# What are the implications of storing the alternative situation (that could have been experienced) in the replay buffer?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl, experience-replay

Consider an environment where there are 2 outcomes (e.g. dead and alive) and a discrete set of actions. For example, a game where the agent has 2 guns $A$ and $B$ to shoot a monster (the monster dies only if the correct gun is used).

Let's say we store the experience $e_1 = (s,a_1, r_1, s'_1)$ in the replay buffer $D$, where

- $s$: we have the monster to kill
- $a_1$: choose and use gun $A$
- $r_1$: $-1$ (the wrong gun)
- $s'_1$: monster is alive

But we also save the alternative situation $e_2 = (s, a_2, r_2, s'_2)$ in the replay buffer $D$, where

- $s$: the same state (we have the monster)
- $a_2$: choose and use gun $B$
- $r_2$: $(-1) * r = 1$
- $s'_2$: the monster is dead

I can't find a topic about this technique, or don't know what to look for.

Comment: It looks like for this scenario "if" statement could be the best option. Something like this: "if beast.kind == 1: gans.use.A() else: gans.use.B()".

Comment: When you ask "What are the implications", what do you mean exactly? Do you mean the "implications in terms of convergence to the right solution during learning/training"? **Please**, edit your post to clarify this point. Anyway, the closest thing to what you're proposing that I am aware of is [Hindsight Experience Replay](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/453fadbd8a1a3af50a9df4df899537b5-Paper.pdf), but they don't store the alternative tuple, but change the trajectories that are experienced so that they become "falsely successful".

Comment: What do you mean by using "IF" statement, the state has +100 features (image and sound), i don't know what should be used "hence the use of the RL".

Comment: nbro; it's more of a problem of Sample efficiency, and i'm thinking of reversing the states to extend the sample size (as data augmentation). logically it should help, but the loss diverge after a while.

Comment: @KimbooRasta Please, tag me with `@nbro` (like I'm tagging you), otherwise I will not see your comments. I saw your comments only by chance.

Comment: @KimbooRasta Well, if you do what you suggest, you're basically assuming that those transitions were observed by the behaviour policy. Are you using DQN (i.e. an off-policy algorithm) or something else?